# How to re-use a Jquery .each .... as a separate method to pass various elements to

Tags: jquery

I'm still getting my feet wet with jQuery.

I have a table that I refresh every few seconds via Ajax.  I am using this particular bit of code to have it highlight new rows only (and fade them) after a refresh of the table contents:

```
$("#log_table tr.new_row").each(function (){
   var oldBGcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF33"}, "fast").delay(3000).animate({backgroundColor: oldBGcolor}, 3000).removeClass("new_row");
});
```

I'd like to turn this .each into a separate function so that I can have it act on a different table.  And I anticipate perhaps re-using this for a third table as well (all on the same page, mind you).

How do I alter this code and then "pass" my table to it?  I'm sure this is easy, I just couldn't think of the write words to Google this on.

Thanks!

-= Dave =-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming each table will have a unique id...  So in the example below you have your log_table, another table called log_table2, and a third table called log_table3.

```
animateTable("log_table");
animateTable("log_table2");
animateTable("log_table3");

function animateTable(tableName){
    $("#" + tableName +" tr.new_row").each(function (){
       var oldBGcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
       $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF33"}, "fast").delay(3000).animate({backgroundColor: oldBGcolor}, 3000).removeClass("new_row");
    });
}
```

Alternatively add a class attribute (in this example called 'animate-table-class' to each table and use this call once:

```
$(".animate-table-class tr.new_row").each(function (){
   var oldBGcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF33"}, "fast").delay(3000).animate({backgroundColor: oldBGcolor}, 3000).removeClass("new_row");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, okay.  I guess I'd spotted some way of doing it more dynamically on the $() contents... somewhere in my browsing a few days ago.   Some way that you could send that .each just about any element you wanted.    Guess I should have "broadened" things a bit in my question.

Comment: Adding a class to the table and then using that class in the $() selector would be another way of doing it without having to name and call a function for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to give every table same class for example "table-class" and just do

```
$("#log_table.table-class tr.new_row").each(function (){
   var oldBGcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF33"}, "fast")
          .delay(3000)
          .animate({backgroundColor: oldBGcolor}, 3000)
          .removeClass("new_row");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the table ID as a parameter

```
function highlightNewRows(tableId){
    $("#" + tableId + " tr.new_row").each(function (){
        var oldBGcolor = $(this).css("background-color");
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF33"},"fast")
                .delay(3000)
                .animate({backgroundColor: oldBGcolor}, 3000)
                .removeClass("new_row");
    });
}
```